# -o-backface-visibility Not Working in Opera?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

**So I'm working with this CSS 3D Transformation on hover...**

**Works:** Webkit, FF
**Not Working:** Opera
**Untested:** IE

From what I can tell from Chris's article here Opera does support -o-backface-visibility (see browser support table at bottom). The property does not seem to be sticking in Opera though, even in his examples. However, he does seem to manage a fallback on hover for Opera, so if I could get that far I'd be content, but I'm not there yet.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/YHeKX/

(wat...there's no easy way to paste in my fiddle code? There has to be...)

```
<div class="flip"> 
  <div class="card"> 
    <div class="face front">Front</div> 
    <div class="face back">Back</div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

AND

```
   .flip {
   position: relative;
   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
   -moz-perspective: 1000;
   -ms-perspective: 1000;
   -o-perspective: 1000;
   margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.card {
   width: 200px; 
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transition: 0.5s;
   -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -ms-transition: 0.5s;
   -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -o-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip:hover .card {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);                
}
.face {
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   color: white;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
}
.no-hide .face {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
   -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
   -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
   -o-backface-visibility: visible;
}
.front {
   background: red;
   z-index: 10;
}
.back {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   background: green; 
}
.flip:hover .front {
   z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, after rebuilding one of the article demos - this might be a better solution that does not require any jQuery and is working(albeit without transitions - in Opera): jsfiddle.net/uxable/acbnS

Comment: Updated the original post code to the non-js working-but-not-ideal in Opera solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not working.

In [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/CSS/backface-visibility) no support for Opera. In Opera Presto specifications it's out. [Link to search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3awww.opera.com/docs/specs/%20backface-visibility)